# How to send the selected drop-down value in the popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have more than 8-12 fields in the form. I have one select drop-down field called as `status`. It displays the selected value by default from the database.

For example, By default drop-down selected is `Create`.

```
<select class="select_control" name="o_order_status" id="o_order_status">
    <option value="1" <?php echo ($post->o_order_status == '1') ? 'selected':''; ?>>Create</option>
    <option value="-1" <?php echo ($post->o_order_status == '-1') ? 'selected':''; ?>>Pending</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo ($post->o_order_status == '2') ? 'selected':''; ?>>Verified</option>
</select>
```

Now I have to change the status from `Create` to `Pending or Verified`. So I am using the change event and on the alert, I am getting the value. Also, I am showing the popup to write a message which is displaying.

```
$(function() {
    $("#o_order_status").change(function() {
          alert( this.value );// here I am getting the onchange value
        $('#popup_verify').show();// display the popup
    });
});
```

Till now everything is working, My issue is, I have to pass the select drop-down- value in the popup form to update the information in the database. or is there any other way to handle this issue?

My popup is,

```
<div class="popup" id="popup_verify" style="display:none;">
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <textarea placeholder="message" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
    </form>
</div>
```

**full code**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#o_order_status").change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
    $('#popup_verify').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<select class="select_control" name="o_order_status" id="o_order_status">
  <option value="1" <?php echo ($post->o_order_status == '1') ? 'selected':''; ?>>Create</option>
  <option value="-1" <?php echo ($post->o_order_status == '-1') ? 'selected':''; ?>>Pending</option>
  <option value="2" <?php echo ($post->o_order_status == '2') ? 'selected':''; ?>>Verified</option>
</select>

<div class="popup" id="popup_verify" style="display:none;">
  <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <textarea placeholder="message" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using Select Change Handler

```
$(".select_control").change(function() {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    $("[name='update']").val(selectedValue);
    alert('new input value: ' + $("[name='update']").val()); 
});
```

## ...or Using Ajax:

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(event){ //handle the submission of your form from popup
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents form default action
    var selectedValue = $('.select_control').val(); // get the selected value from dropdown
    $.ajax({ //do ajax to do update
        type: "POST",
        url: 'process.php', // url to your .php file
        data: {'post_data':selectedValue}, // use $_POST['post_data'] to access in php
        success: function(dataReturned){ //callback function if request success. dataReturned is what you echoed out in php
            alert('data updated');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, give me some time to implement this. There is some internet issue at my area.

Comment: You're gonna want to use the **Using Select Change Handler** if you want the user to redirect to the process.php ... alternatively you can use the **Using Ajax** method if you want to just run the process.php script without reloading the current page

Comment: Yes, I tried your code and it's working for me. I tried AJAX process

Comment: Ah, nice. Please accept as answer if it helped, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help, upvote from my side for the two ansers

Comment: I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

vanilla Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('form_input_id').value = 'your value';
```

with jQuery:

```
$("#form_input_id").val("your value");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Where Should I use this?